# Sanitize a $_REQUEST[object] to satisfy the phpcs standards for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, phpcs

Is there a way to sanitize a $_REQUEST[object] to satisfy the phpcs standards for WordPress? Below is what I have so far but phpcs still errors on the earliest assignment of the request and I cannot figure out how to sanitize without first assigning.

```
if ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'delete' === $_REQUEST['action'] ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['action2'] ) && 'delete' === $_REQUEST['action2'] ) ) {
    $nonce = isset( $_REQUEST['delete_bulk'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['delete_bulk'] ) ) : '';

    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'delete_bulk' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['bulkcheck'] ) ) {
            $checks    = $_REQUEST['bulkcheck']; // This generates phpcs errors.
            $bulkcheck = array();
            foreach ( $checks as $key => $val ) {
                $bulkcheck[ $key ] = ( isset( $checks[ $key ] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $val ) ) : '';
            }
        }
        $this->quotes_delete_bulk( $bulkcheck );
        header( 'Location: ' . get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=My-Plugin' );
    } else {
        $this->msg = $this->nonce_error();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [sanitize_key()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/)

```
if ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'delete' === $_REQUEST['action'] ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['action2'] ) && 'delete' === $_REQUEST['action2'] ) ) {
    $nonce = isset( $_REQUEST['delete_bulk'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['delete_bulk'] ) ) : '';

    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'delete_bulk' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['bulkcheck'] ) ) {
            $checks    = sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['bulkcheck'] ); // This generates phpcs errors.
            $bulkcheck = array();
            foreach ( $checks as $key => $val ) {
                $bulkcheck[ $key ] = ( isset( $checks[ $key ] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $val ) ) : '';
            }
        }
        $this->quotes_delete_bulk( $bulkcheck );
        header( 'Location: ' . get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=My-Plugin' );
    } else {
        $this->msg = $this->nonce_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I select say 10 records to be deleted:
`$checks = $_REQUEST['bulkcheck'];`
returns:
`array(10) { [0]=> string(4) "2027" [1]=> string(4) "2026" [2]=> string(4) "2025" [3]=> string(4) "2024" [4]=> string(4) "2023" [5]=> string(4) "2022" [6]=> string(4) "2021" [7]=> string(4) "2020" [8]=> string(4) "2019" [9]=> string(4) "2018" }`

When I sanitize and unslash.
returns:
`string(0) ""`

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try sanitize_key().

Comment: Same result: `string(0) ""`